# For any non-zero complex number $\beta$, at least one of the two numbers $\beta $ and $e^\beta$ is transcendental.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-number-theory

I want to show the following statement. Please give me a hint.

For any non-zero complex number $\beta$, at least one of the two numbers $\beta $  and $e^\beta$ is transcendental.

Comment: I assume that you mean $a + bi$ is algebraic iff $a$ and $b$ are algebraic. Therefore, if $a + bi$ is transcendental then at least one of $a$ or $b$ is transcendental. So, all complex transcendental numbers are"based on real transcendental numbers. Also, can a transcendental complex number to the power transcendental number be rational?

Comment: this is Lindemann Theorem which establishes the transcendentality of $\pi$ since $e^{i\pi}=-1$ It is quite non-trivial and a proof can be found in the usual texts (eg Baker etc) and on wikipedia say https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem